# Comeager sets in the Cantor Space

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

For any set $A \subset \omega$, the characteristic function $\chi_A: \omega \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ of $A$ is a point in the Cantor Space $2^{\omega}$. With this identification, any ultrafilter $p \in \beta \omega$ can be seen as a subset of the Cantor Space, $p = \{ \chi_A \, | \, A \in p\} \subset 2^{\omega}$.
We can do the sabe thing for superfilters (which are simply unions of ultrafilters).
There are no comeager ultrafilters in $2^{\omega}$ (nor meager), but clearly there are comeager superfilters ($\mathcal{P}(\omega)$).
Is there a characterization for a superfilter to be comeager in $2^{\omega}$? Or a characterization for a subset of $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ to be comeager in $2^{\omega}$?
References are very welcome.
Thanks

Comment: An ultraflter is "half" of the Cantor set. Hence neither meagre nor co-meagre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A union $\mathcal X$ of ultrafilters (usually called a co-ideal) on $\omega$ is comeager if and only if there is a partition of $\omega$ into finite intervals $I_0,I_1,I_2,\dots$ such that every union of infinitely many of the $I_n$'s is in $\mathcal X$.

This is a reformulation of a theorem of Talagrand characterizing meager filters. A filter $\mathcal F$ on $\omega$ is meager iff there is a partition into intervals as above such that every set in $\mathcal F$ intersects all but finitely many of the intervals $I_n$. The reformulation is based on the fact that co-ideals and filters correspond to each other via $\mathcal X=\{A\subseteq\omega : \omega-A\notin F\}$. (Just as co-ideals are unions of ultrafilters, filters are intersections of ultrafilters.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just got curious about one other thing: a coideal is a union of ultrafilters, so is there a characterization of comeager coideals in terms of the ultrafilters composing it?